# La función no elimina el dato

Tags: c, funciones

*Se supone que esta función debe eliminar un "jugador" de la lista al ingresar el ID del jugador pero parece que solo realiza la búsqueda, ya que al llamar otra función que muestra todos los jugadores de la lista incluso el jugador que debía estar eliminado, si quieren pongo el codigo completo pero son de 286 lineas.*

```
void baja()
{
   FILE *arch;
    arch=fopen("informacion.txt","r+b");
    if (arch==NULL)
        exit(1);
    printf("\n\t\t Ingrese el ID del jugador a eliminar:");
    int cod;
    int opciondebaja;
    scanf("%i", &cod);
    tjugador jugador;
    int existe=0;
    fread(&jugador, sizeof(tjugador), 1, arch);
    while(!feof(arch))
    {
        if (cod==jugador.ID)
        {
            printf("\n\t\tID: %i",jugador.ID);
            printf("\n\t\tNombre : %s",jugador.nombres);
            printf("\n\t\tApellido paterno : %s",jugador.apellidopa);
            printf("\n\t\tApellido materno : %s",jugador.apellidoma);
            printf("\n\t\tFecha de nacimiento: %s",jugador.nacimiento);
            printf("\n\t\tCorreo electronico: %s",jugador.correoelec);
            printf("\n\t\tNumero telefonico: %s",jugador.numerotel);
            printf("\n\t\tContrase%ca: %s",164,jugador.contrasena);
            printf("\n\t\tConfirma la baja del trabajador? 1=Si / 2=No: ");

            fflush(stdin);

            scanf("%i", &opciondebaja);

            if(opciondebaja==1){
                printf("\n\t\t Jugador eliminado");
            }
            else if(opciondebaja==0){
                printf("\n\t\t Acción cancelada");
            }
        }

        fread(&jugador, sizeof(tjugador), 1, arch);
    }
```

Comment: NOTA soy nuevo, según yo la pregunta es corta, describo el problema, hay un pedazo de código como muestra que no vine a que solo me hagan mi tarea y que también lo intente, estoy en el foro de español y creo que son todos las cosas por las que se han quejado la vez anterior que  pregunte algo aquí

Comment: Hola! Todo bien, gracias por esforzarte en compartirnos una buena pregunta. ¿Cuando intentas eliminar el dato, sale algún error? Y, cuando menos, incluye el fragmento que pinta la lista de jugadores

Comment: 0

El código compila bien el único error es cuando en vez de insertar una ID registrada insertas algo que no existe o que no esta como una ID y se repite un bucle infinito

Comment: y si encuentra el archivo y el id correspondiente, porque te pregunta si ese es el que quieres eliminar y te muestra todos los datos, pero al momento de checar si en verdad lo elimino, no lo elimino

Comment: Las aclaraciones van EN la pregunta, yendo a [edit]. Acá se pierden :) Los comentarios son pa los que intentamos entender tu problema, tú respondes a eso editando la pregunta y añadiendo cosas.

Comment: Yo prefiriría que añadieras el código completo, para así poder ejecutarlo todo, ver todo el panorama, e intentar resolver tu problema. En mi opinión lapregunta está bien formulada. : )

Comment: La pregunta está razonablemente bien formulada. **Pero** ... dices que no elimina el dato ... ¿ Dónde está el código que realiza la eliminación ? Porque solo muestras como pregunta. O tal vez sea yo que no lo veo, pero según mi lógica, una eliminación por fuerza ha de llevar asociado algún tipo de escritura ... ¿ podrías compartir el código de eliminación, o detallar la lógica que estás siguiendo ? En la pregunta, no tienes mas que pulsar en [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/543713/edit). Un saludo.